# How do I make custom templates for django_social_share?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I have followed every steps in installing and using django-social-share.
When I loaded social_share on my detail page where I want it displayed, it worked fine using the default templates.
Nothing was displayed when I tried to override the default templates. I have the template in root_dir/templates/templatetags/post_to_facebook.html.
I don't know why nothing displayed when I try to use those custom templates- neither the custom templates nor the default one displayed.
Any help will be appreciated.

**Here's my files**
**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Local apps
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',

    # Third party
    'django_social_share',
    'crispy_forms',


.
.
.

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
.
.
.
```

**post_to_facebook.html**

```
<span class="w3-badge w3-hover-blue facebook-this">
    <a href="{{ facebook_url }}" class="w3-xlarge" target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
</span>
```

**post_to_twitter.html**

```
<span class="w3-badge w3-hover-blue tweet-this">
    <a href="{{ tweet_url }}" class="w3-xlarge meta-act-link meta-tweet" target="_blank" title="Share on Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
</span>
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load social_share %}
{% load static %}



{% block title %} {{ post.title }} {% endblock title %}
{% block content %}  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">

    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>  
    <p class="date">Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
    </p>
    {{ post.body|linebreaks }} 

    <p><a href="{% url 'post_edit' post.pk post.slug %}">Edit</a> | 
        <a href="{% url 'post_delete' post.pk post.slug %}">Delete</a></p> 
        <p>Back to <a href="{% url 'post_list' %}">Forum</a>.</p> 
        {% post_to_twitter post.title post %} 
        {% post_to_facebook post %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are styling the html template. File path should be root_dir/templates/django_social_share/templatetags/post_to_facebook.html.

You can see the details on the project page https://pypi.org/project/django-social-share/#id1

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did

```
<div class="social">
    {% send_email post.get_absolute_url "Share via Email" %}
</div>
<script>
    socialButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.social div > a');
    socialButtons.forEach(node => {
        node.classList.add('btn','btn-primary');
    });
</script>
```